# Trackpad/trackpoint stops working every few minutes: 19.04, Thinkpad X220

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 19.04, thinkpad

a bit of an annoying problem manifested after my [ThinkPad x220](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/my/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x220) suddenly crashed. Everything worked perfectly before.

Now, every few minutes, an error occurs when using my trackpad/trackpoint. The errors include:

-no function at all 
-only right click
-left click permanent or 'sticky'

When this happens, I enter

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

After which, I can use it again... for a few minutes (or longer, if I'm lucky).

I've tried following advice at other forums, including entering

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.proto=exps"

into /etc/default/grub

which didn't seem to have an effect (apart from an undesirable one, that I cannot turn off the touchpad to use only the touchpoint 'nipple' in the middle of the keyboard, as they now seem to be treated as identical).

I would very much appreciate any help. Thanks :)

Comment: look in dmesg. Im thinking maybe you have an issue with ehci or xhci but dmesg should say something. I would look for errors that repeat, or possibly things like high current draw.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions: I have solved this problem, but not sure how as I tried multiple things: most likely xinput config. I now have another problem instead (trackpoint works but doesn't show up in xinput, and therefore I can't turn off trackpad and leave trackpoint working, which I usually do), but I'll start another question for that.